# Size limit on E-mail attachments when checking if it is Spam?

Tags: email-attachments, email-spam, spamassassin

I am trying to assess the **Spamminess** of E-mails. The emails are received in **Maildir** (on Linux server) via **Postfix**.

I am completely new to the E-mail domain. So I am curious about the following things:

1. **Do the emails with attachments usually pass through the spam filters**?
2. **Is there a size limit (attachment size) that decides this?**

My actual question is **(when the emails have attachments) will SpamAssassin take longer than usual to assess the email?** I am using the Linux version of Apache SpamAssassin.

I can easily extract different parts of the email (including images/PDFs) with JavaMail but, at the end, when I try to pass the file to SpamAssassin, the process never ends. It works fine for smaller attachments (30-40 KB) though.

Did anyone face the same problem? Suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling SpamAssassin? As part of the delivery process or is it called by the user once the file is in the maildir?

Comment: @Ángel: At the moment I am passing it to SpamAssassin once the email is stored as a file in Maildir. Do you think doing it the other way is better?

Comment: it's just that it may be relevant. What happens when you call SpamAssassing manually with those files?

Comment: @Ángel: When I send the email file with attachments manually to Spamassassin, it works fine. But when automate the same thing (e.g. via Java processbuilder), the process somehow does not move ahead, neither it throws an error. The spamassassin output file remains empty.

Comment: Good. That means there is something different between running it manually and through Java processbuilder. You now need to figure it out the difference. Perhaps some environment variable is missing?